# SQuirrelSQL redirect ouput to a file?

Tags: redirection

Does anybody knows if SQuirrel SQL client may output the of several SQL commands to a single result window in textplain or to a file ( as SQL+ would )

So I can:

```
 select * from dual;
 select * from dual;
```

And have both results in a single "ready to" Ctrl-C format?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SQuirreL, but this works on every SQL variant I have tried:

```
select * from dual;
union all
select * from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out where to specify the output format. 
With this I could at least copy/paste the output but still I have to click on each tab result.

I guess this would do for now.

[image]